# How to specify additional parameters for GNU sort's --compress-program option?

Tags: shell, sort, compression, arguments

`sort --compress-program=/bin/gzip` works fine, but how can I pass options down to the compression programm (e.g. `--best` or `--fast`)?

`sort --compress-program=/bin/gzip\ --best` failes with the error message

> couldn't execute compress program

as do `sort --compress-program="/bin/gzip --best"` and `sort --compress-program=/bin/gzip\\\ --best`.

Google-ing the error returned nothing but the source code generating the message.

Is there any way to do this without writing a wrapper or defining an alias?

Comment: Pretty sure a wrapper script is the only way to do this - I imagine sort just treats whatever it gets as the binary name and doesn't try to split arguments.

Comment: @Graeme: It just feels totally over-complicated to write a script consisting of 2 words + a shebang, make it executable and use this to raplace such a common tool.

Comment: @RuiFRibero: What was wrong with me being desparate?

Answer (score 6):

Many of the compressors take an an environment variable to accept options that cannot be passed on the command line. In your case

```
GZIP_OPT=-9 sort --compress-program=/bin/gzip
```

The same is true for `xz` with `XZ_OPT` and `bzip2` with `BZIP2`

Comment: Nice suggestion, this seems to work, too. However, as pointed out by @devnull, this option is not named consistantly and to me it feels as hacky and over-complicated as writing a wrapper or setting up an alias.

Comment: @devnull: the `export` shouldn't be necessary if you define the environment variable on the same line as in @bdowning's answer.

Comment: Another downside of this solution is that if you pass the option from a calling script/Makefile, you need to a) split it and b) figure out the name of the environment variable. I would like to be able to have a parameter like `gzip --best` or `xz -0` that I just pass down to `sort`. But anyhow, thx for your fast reply and a nice idea.

Comment: The compressors added this specifically to solve this class of problem for arg passing. It's not a hack, that's how they solved a problem not of their making. Only the {t}csh variants require an `export`.

Comment: But still, it seems impossible to write a shell script that can take `gzip --best` or `xz -o` as a parameter and use this as compression tool for `sort`. If I was to do this using your solution, I would have to know all possible compression tools and the corresponding environment variables. If somebody writes a `my_compress` that works `STDIN` to `STOUT` and supports `-d` for de-compression it would be impossible for this user to run my script passing `my_compress --method=rle` as the compression method to be used by `sort`. So they didn't *solve* the problem, they just hacked around it. ;)